# How to train LSTM/GRU using unsupervised learning method before train it with supervised learning method in Keras?

Tags: keras

Correct me if i'm wrong, but i saw an article somewhere that says that training neural net using unsupervised method before using it for supervised classification will give a better result. I assume it is like a transfer learning kind of stuff. But i'm wondering if i wanted to train the LSTM without the labels, it cannot be entered to the `fit` function of keras. Any idea how to do it?